# How to pass URL in URL (as GET parameter) using PHP?

Tags: php, apache, url, parameters, get

I'm having some problems passing URL's as GET parameter. When I try to access:

http://www.linkebuy.com.br/linkebuy/parceiro?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

I get the following message:

[image: Unexpected error.]

However, if I go for:

http://www.linkebuy.com.br/linkebuy/parceiro?url=123

Everything works just fine (it redirects to an inexistent site - 123 -, of course, but it does the expected). By elimination I can say there's something wrong with the `url` parameter, but what is it?

**OBS:** I'm using `rawurlencode()` to encode the URL.

**EDIT:** *Code you asked...*

In the first view, where the link is (http://www.linkebuy.com.br/notebook/detalhe?id=5):

```
<!-- url() function just completes the right URL (production or development) -->
<a href="<?php echo url('linkebuy/parceiro/?url=' . rawurlencode($l->getUrl()), true) ?>" class="<?php echo $leadClass ?> oferta" target="_blank">
    <?php echo $l->getNomeFantasia() ?>
</a>
```

When clicked the link redirects to an action (`/linkebuy/parceiro`), where happens the following (basicly nothing, just keeping in the framework):

```
public function execute($request, $response) {
    $response->addParameter('url', rawurldecode($request->getParameter('url', ''))); //This creates $url in the view
    $response->setTemplate('site/linkebuy/lead-parceiro.php'); //Forwards to the view
}
```

It includes the view, `lead-parceiro.php` (above on the question, I link to this page), where the head contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){ window.location = '<?php echo $url ?>'; },3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Use simple `urlencode()` and tell us if that makes any difference.

Comment: No difference at all.

Comment: The problem is in your redirect function....show us the code ;)

Comment: `http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com` is urlencoded

Comment: You probably don't have valid `DirectoryIndex` value in Apache config, please try with `/parceiro/index.php?url=`.

Comment: Show the code of the `parceiro` script.

Comment: I think is probably an apache config restriction not allowing to have http:// on your querystring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't get rid of the restriction you can pass the url in 2 parts like this

```
http://www.linkebuy.com.br/linkebuy/parceiro?protocol=http&url=www.google.com
```

And then parse it on your code to make the full url for the redirect.

Comment: YEAH! You're right! How can I get this fixed? I mean, fix the apache config.

Comment: I'm not sure, this is probably a rewrite rule cheking your querystring. Look at the .htaccess files and the apache conf files to find it.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, as your site is at hostgator, the accepted answer must be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992219/http-in-query-string-does-not-work

Comment: For those who are searching for an alternative answer, you can `base64_encode` the URL and `base64_decode` it later.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `urlencode` when you pass anything as URL parameter