# Pass GET param which is another URL with PHP - Codeigniter 3, Apache

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-3

I want to pass URL in GET param like this :

> SITE URL/b16ee4f31e17df0d3af5?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F

I am using `urlencode` to escape characters, but I see `403 Error` for this URL, because of some of the characters in the URL GET parameter in this case the dot character.

If I use CI3 function `url_title`, it will escape dot characters, but I need them because I need valid url in GET parameter.

How can I pass URL get parameter with in some cases with characters like `. & ? \` and other characters which can be found in the standart URL ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass URL in URL (as GET parameter) using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254112/how-to-pass-url-in-url-as-get-parameter-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in your config file

```
Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
```

**Also you can do this:**

**Step 1:** `$newurl = urlencode(base64_encode('http://google.com'));`

Then you will have a string, pass that string as GET parameter and parse it back using:

```
$realUrl = base64_decode(urldecode($param1));
```

Where `$param1` means the first param of your controller.

**Step 2:** add `=` to your `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in your config file

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

add the character what you trying to pass on GET Url. This configure is store on `config.php` of config folder.

Answer (score -1):

The url has already been encoded(that is if you just copied and pasted it from the address bar) so you can use it with further encoding

Comment: i meant #without further encoding.  You can also urlencode() it on sending and urldecode() on receiving